# use sencha touch 2 to connect facebook

Tags: facebook, extjs, oauth-2.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [using oAuth in sencha touch 2 to connect facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929901/using-oauth-in-sencha-touch-2-to-connect-facebook)

I want my sencha touch 2  mobile app to connect to the facebook. Is this possible using sencha ? I believe oauth 2.0 is required for authenication. Can this be done with ext js? I've looked around and only found oauth v1 libraries that too for javascript and jquery mobile only. Also, are there any APIs working with facebook that works with sencha touch 2?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the Facebook JavaScript SDK with Sencha without any trouble. Facebook's JS SDK loads asynchronously, and provides its own load event for when the SDK is ready to use.

You can implement client-side authentication without relying on Sencha, or triggered via interaction with Sencha UI components. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/client-side/ for the client-side authentication flow, and http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/demos/ for an example of this in action (Jog With Friends).

Comment: Jog With Friends works with mobile web but when i created apk file and installed , it didnt worked ... i guess beacuse of call back url

Comment: There's a few reasons why that might not work, including auth flow and deep-links. You should look at using the Android SDK if you're building a native app.